# Redis memory usage vs space taken up by back ups

Tags: redis

I'm looking at Redis backed up rdb files for a web application. There are 4 such files (for 4 different redis servers working concurrently), sizes being: `13G + 1.6G + 66M + 14M = ~15G`

However, these same 4 instances seem to be taking `43.8GB` of memory (according to new relic). Why such a large discrepancy between how much space redis data takes up in mem vs disk? Could it be a misconfiguration and can the issue be helped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any problem.

First of all, the data is stored in compressed format in rdb file so that the size is less than what it is in memory. How small the rdb file is depends on the type of data, but it can be around 20-80% of the memory used by redis

Another reason your memory usage could be more than the actual usage(you can compare the memory from new relic to the one obtained from redis-cli info memory command) is because of memory fragmentation. Whenever redis needs more memory, it will get the memory allocated from the OS, but will not release it easilyly(when the key expires or is deleted). This is not a big issue, as redis will ask for more memory only after using the extra memory that it has. You can also check the memory fragmentation using redis-cli info memory command.

Comment: Interesting insight. Tell me one thing. What's the best way to check - in your experience - to check which key patterns are employing the most space (and thus are candidates for sanitisation)? `redis-cli --bigkeys` is kind of arbitrary.

Comment: have a look at redis-rdb-tools. Given a rdb, it can generate a csv with all the keys and their sizes. Thereafter you can just play with excel. Or you can also get the size of a particular key. scanning a big rdb with rdb-tools takes some time, but totally worth it.

Comment: Also, Redis will take double memory for BGSAVE process temporarily (using method copy-on-write, forking dataset) to save data on disc or perform a full sync between master and slaves. You might see memory utilization spikes in NRC. This process might fail if out of memory.